# Error in newly created Android Project on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm having some trouble creating Android Projects on Eclipse. Everything was setup accordingly and everytime I try to create one, I get this kind of message in the manifest (several times):

> [2015-05-07 01:18:35 - Ecalc] C:\Users\Luis\Dropbox\UFSC\TCC\Eclipse\Ecalc\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Additionally, it seems that Eclipse doesn't recognize any of the Android related syntax, filling the code with error warnings. Do you guys have any idea of what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all import appcompat-v7 from this address to your worksoace:
android-sdk/extras/android/support/appcompatv7

set android:targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml and project.properties to 22

make sure you have Api level 22 in sdk folder

clean your work space

its should solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

You app require **appcompatv7** 
try to import it and add as library your app

Answer (score 1):

Set project targetSDK to 21 also in project.properties make target as target=android-21